# Print a message if data is not found in table

Tags: sql, oracle

Query to get the name of employee, and the project names of all the employees. Note: Employees with no project should have text “Project not found”

These are the two tables:

```
Table1: EmployeeID, FirstName

1 Vikas
2 nikita
3 Ashish
4 Nikhil
5 anish
```

```
Table2: EmployeeDetailID, ProjectName

1 Task Track
1 CLP
1 Survey Managment
2 HR Managment
3 Task Track
3 GRS
3 DDS
4 HR Managment
6 GL Managment
```

I have used the following query to get employee name and project name on which they are working.

```
select FirstName,ProjectName  from table1,table2 where EmployeeID=EmployeeDetailID;
```

I don't know how to print message for the employee which is not working in any project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [(left) outer join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Joins.html#GUID-29A4584C-0741-4E6A-A89B-DCFAA222994A) to include records from table 1 which have no matching records in table 2; and then use `nvl()` or `coalesce()` to provide a fixed value for null project name values in the rows with no match:

```
select FirstName, coalesce(ProjectName, 'Project not found') as ProjectName
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.EmployeeDetailID = t1.EmployeeID;

FIRSTNAME  PROJECTNAME      
---------- -----------------
Vikas      Task Track       
Vikas      CLP              
Vikas      Survey Managment 
nikita     HR Managment     
Ashish     Task Track       
Ashish     GRS              
Ashish     DDS              
Nikhil     HR Managment     
anish      Project not found
```

You *can* use the old-style syntax with comma-separated table names and the join conditions in the `where` clause, but it's better to use ANSI join syntax; and it's much easier to do so for outer joins, instead of Oracle's hard-to-get-right `(+)` mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use left outer join and  NVL() function. As an example Please find the below query.

`SELECT e.firstname,NVL(d.deptname, 'NO DEPT FOUND') 
    FROM employee E 
LEFT OUTER JOIN department D ON e.deptno = d.deptno;`